# How to get my footer at the bottom instead of the top?

Tags: html, css

I'm making the footer for my website and it seems to sit at the bottom when my page is full-sized but when I change the size of my screen my footer seems to show up at the top. I inserted an image to show you the issue I'm talking about. It seems that my footer isn't large enough on the bottom because some of my text isn't showing up but when I make the screen size smaller all my missing info is at the top of the page. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

[![The black is supposed to be my footer and it heads to the top of my screen when i make the screen smaller][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSZdS.png

```css
  body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Open+Sans", sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #0C133C;
}

#nav {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav {
  float: right;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav>li {
  display: Inline-block;
  padding: 20px 50px 10px 9px;
}

.nav>li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #0C133C;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.clearer {
  clear: both;
}

.subnav class {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.subnav>div a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #0C133C;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 20px 30px 10px 9px;
}

.logo {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.subnav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}

.split {
  width: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.centered {
  text-align: center;
}

.left {
  left: 0;
  background-color: #282C41;
  color: white;
  margin-top: .5rem;
}

h1 {
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-size: 35px;
  bottom: 20px;
}

p1 {
  font-size: 30;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-left: 120px;
  clear: both
}

.row .column img {
  width: 100px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.right {
  right: 0;
  background-color: #CDCDCD;
  margin-top: .5rem;
  font-size: 18px;
}

input,
select {
  position: relative;
  left: 140px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 3px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.button {
  background-color: #282C41;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-left: 225px;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

p {
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.txt {
  color: #0000C6;
}

.txt:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #0000C6
}

p2 {
  font-size: 18px;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #111;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100% padding-top: 40px;
  color: #fff;
}

.footer-content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer-content h3 {
  font-size: 2.1rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  line-height: 3rem;
}

.footer-content p {
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #cacdd2;
}

.socials {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 1rem 0 3rem 0;
}

.socials li {
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.socials a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1.1px solid white;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.socials a i {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  width: 20px;
  transition: color .4s ease;
}

.socials a:hover i {
  color: aqua;
}

.footer-bottom {
  background: #000;
  width: 100vw;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer-bottom p {
  float: left;
  font-size: 14px;
  word-spacing: 2px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.footer-bottom p a {
  color: #44bae8;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.footer-bottom span {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  opacity: .4;
  font-weight: 200;
}

.footer-menu {
  float: right;
}

.footer-menu ul {
  display: flex;
}

.footer-menu ul li {
  padding-right: 10px;
  display: block;
}

.footer-menu ul li a {
  color: #cfd2d6;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.footer-menu ul li a:hover {
  color: #27bcda;
}

@media (max-width:500px) {
  .footer-menu ul {
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f04ec83bb3.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Navbar</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" </head>

  <body>
    <div class="navbar">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Sign In</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="clearer"></div>
    </div>
    <subnav class="subnav subnav-light bg-light">
      <img src="universallogo.jpg" class="logo" />
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="subnav=brand" href="#">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Bonds</a>
        </a>
        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Report a Claim</a>
        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">About Us</a>
        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Search</a>
      </div>
    </subnav>
    <div class="flex-container">
      <div class="split left">
        <div class="centered">
          <h1>GET YOUR LICENSE & PERMIT BONDS FAST & EASY</h1>
          <p1>We provide our Customers with a fast, easy, and secure way to get bonded. Get your Free Quote in minutes.
          </p1>
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="column">
            <img src="Demotech.png" alt="rating" style="width:150%">
          </div>
          <br><br>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="column">
              <img src="USTreasury.png" alt="treas" style="width:40%">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="split right">
        <form name="form1" id="form1" action="/action_page.php">
          <select name="subject" id="subject">
            <option value="" selected="selected">Select Your State</option>
            <option value="California">California</option>
            <option value="California">Illinois</option>
            <option value="California">Michigan</option>
            <option value="California">Ohio</option>
          </select>
          <br><br>
          <select name="topic" id="topic">
            <option value="" selected="selected">Who is requring the bond</option>
          </select>
          <br><br>
          <select name="chapter" id="chapter">
            <option value="" selected="selected">What jurisdiction is requring the bond</option>
          </select>
          <br><br>
          <select name="chapter" id="chapter">
            <option value="" selected="selected">Select Your Bond</option>
          </select>
          <br><br>
        </form>
        <form action="/action_page.php">
          <input type="text" id="date" name="startdate" placeholder="Effective Start Date">
          <br><br>
          <input type="text" id="email" name="typeemail" placeholder=" Type E-mail">
        </form>
        <br><br>
        <button class="button button4">GET QUOTE NOW</button>
        <p>Don't See Your Bond? <span class="txt">Click Here to Sumbit a Request</span></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
      <div class="footer-content">
        <h3>Universal Fire & Casualty Insurance Company</h3>
        <p>Raj Template is a blog website where you will find great tutorials on web design and development. Here each tutorial is beautifully described step by step with the required source code.</p>
        <ul class="socials">
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="footer-bottom">
        <div class="footer-menu">
          <ul class="f-menu">
            <li><a href="">Help</a></li>
            <li><a href="">FAQ</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please reduce the amount of code signifcantly to the required minimum to reproduce your issue. Noone is going to dig through hundreds of lines of irrelevant code for you.

Comment: Define/clarity "footer" in your question you have `<footer>` and `<div class="footer-content">` and `<div class="footer-bottom">`

Comment: Most often when you have CSS issues like this you have TOO MUCH CSS when a reduction would suffice and make things simpler/easier to fix

Answer (score 0):

When placing the footer at the bottom we need to fill the page with something to mimic placing the footer on the bottom. You can simply set the min-height of your main object to 100vh:

```
main {
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```